# Generate a key in new action that's checked in create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4

New to concepts of security, so I feel like this must have been done before.

For a classic submission form:

```
def new
end

def create
   unless params[:key] != ENV["key"]
   end
end
```

I have on the `new.html.erb` a `hidden_input` with a key that I'm checking in the `create` action. But the problem is that this key is just a static environment variable.

I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically create a new key each time the `new.html.erb` page is rendered, and then have the `create` action check against this dynamic key. This would require a variable generated in the `new` action that I can check against in the `create` action. Output would be something like this:

```
def new
  key = SecureRandom
end

def create
  unless params[:key] != key
  end
end
```

Of course, this solution would also have to work with multiple users simultaneously submitting the form, so that one key doesn't get cross referenced with another request, and then mistakenly rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Rails already provides a level of protection called CSRF-tokens. Within each form, an `authenticity_token` gets generated and inserted as a hidden field. This token is associated with a user's session. Upon submitting a POST request, the `authenticity_token` will be checked.

https://nvisium.com/blog/2014/09/10/understanding-protectfromforgery/

Use `protect_from_forgery` in your controllers to enable this functionality.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html

Comment: i know about CSRF, but I need something custom to verify specific identity of users

Answer (score 0):

It is often a bad idea to implement your own security mechanism. If you don't intent to protect your app against CSRF (this is built-in) and still want to build your own thing, maybe you will be interested in [this rotp feature](https://github.com/mdp/rotp#counter-based-otps).